# Writing style in directive in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm using angular 6 with PrimeNg. And it's `dialog` component `contentStyle` property. If, I write in my html like below, it is working perfectly. But, when I write in my directive (for setting default values of components), its style corrupting. What can be the mistake?

**This working perfectly.**

```
<p-dialog [contentStyle]="{'overflow':'visible'}"></p-dialog>
```

**But when I write like below, its style corrupting.**

```
export class DialogDirective {
  constructor(dialog: Dialog) {
    dialog.responsive = true;
    dialog.modal = true;
    dialog.closeOnEscape = false;
    dialog.contentStyle = "{'overflow':'visible'}";
  }
}

<p-dialog></p-dialog>
```

You can see PrimeNg's dialog from [this link](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog)

Comment: Can you give a stackblitz example?

Comment: Rijins's answer is worked. Thanks @zmag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using property, you should pass object into it not string.

```
export class DialogDirective {
  constructor(dialog: Dialog) {
    dialog.responsive = true;
    dialog.modal = true;
    dialog.closeOnEscape = false;
    dialog.contentStyle = {'overflow':'visible'}; <-- here
  }
}


<p-dialog [contentStyle]="dialog.contentStyle"></p-dialog>
```

Comment: Thanks @rijin. It worked. I thouht that `contentStyle` is string like `style`. But it is `object`